# Custom logging messages hard to distinguish from other logcat messages

Tags: android, logcat, timber-android

In Android Studio's logcat window it is hard to distinguish my custom log messages (Log.d, Log.e...) from the other log messages. This still happens when setting **package:mine**.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber).

In MainApplication class set up a custom class extending Timber.Tree. Then Timber.plant it like this:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Timber.plant(new MyPersonalDebugTree());
} else {
    Timber.plant(new CrashReportingTree());
}
```

The custom Timber.Tree looks like following:

```
public class MyPersonalDebugTree extends Timber.DebugTree {
    @Override
    protected void log(int priority, String tag, @NonNull String message, Throwable t) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message);
        sb.insert(0, "\uD83D\uDC99\uD83D\uDC99\uD83D\uDC99 - ");
        super.log(priority, tag, sb.toString(), t);
    }
}
```

Notice this:

```
sb.insert(0, "\uD83D\uDC99\uD83D\uDC99\uD83D\uDC99 - ");
```

It modifies your log messages and adds a prefix containing ❤️❤️❤️.

[image]